# Adding class names on hover based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a tabbed module which works by getting content that is in the `.content` div (which is hidden) and displaying it in a empty div called `.overview`.

The idea behind this tabbed module is that, on hover (or when class active exists), the content on the right will change based on what header is being selected from the left. I.e. If I hover over a header named "Red", the `.overview` div on the right will spit out "red".

However, the issues I'm having are the following:

1. In the demo below, don't hover on any of the headers. The `.overview` div has no content - which is obviously not ideal. If `.tabs` has class `.active`, then I want its content displayed on the right. I have a counter running which changes class active every 5 seconds. I don't only want to show stuff on hover.
2. Having said the above, if I hover over another `tabs` div, I want the counter to stop - to prevent it from adding class `active` to another `.tabs` div (because the hovered on `tabs` is active.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //  add class .active on li hover
  $('.tabs').mouseenter(function() {
    //$('.tabs').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.tabs').addClass('active');
  });


  // Change active tab every x seconds
  $(function() {
    var list = $(".tabs"),
      currentActive = 0;
    time = 5; // interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
      currentActive = (currentActive + 1) % list.length;
      list.removeClass('active').eq(currentActive).addClass('active');
    }, time * 1000);
  });

})

var overview = $('.overview');

$('.tabs').each(function(i) {
  var thisTab = $(this);
  var thisContent = thisTab.find('.content').html();

  // when class .active exists, change content in .overview
  if ($('.tabs').hasClass('active')) {
    overview.html(thisContent);
  }


  // on hover, change content in .overview
  thisTab.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
      thisTab.addClass('active');
      overview.html(thisContent);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(e) {
      thisTab.removeClass('active');
      overview.html('');
    });

});
```

```css
.tabs.active {
  background: none yellow;
}

.list {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.overview {
  flex-basis: 60%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="list">

    <li class="tabs active">
      <div class="header"><span>Header</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs">
      <div class="header"><span>Header 2</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs">
      <div class="header"><span>Header 3</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>

  </div>
  <div class="overview"> </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I've managed to make some movement on issue 1. I've added:

```
 if ($('.tabs').hasClass('active')) {
     overview.html(thisContent);
  }
```

Which now, without hover, displays content in `.overview`, however, the content doesn't change when another tab is `.active` (i.e. in the demo, don't hover over anything, wait and it just shows content 3 for all headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following (I have commented what I have changed)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $(".tabs"),
    overview = $('.overview'),
    autoInterval,                                    // interval var
    currentActive = 0;                               // make this global to this closure


  overview.html(list.eq(0).find('.content').html()); // set overview content
  startInterval();                                   // start interval straight away

  //  add class .active on li hover
  list.mouseenter(function() {
    var thisTab = $(this);

    currentActive = list.index(this);                // set current active
    list.removeClass('active');                      // remove active class
    thisTab.addClass('active');                      // add active class
    clearInterval(autoInterval);                     // clear the interval whilst hovering

    var thisContent = thisTab.find('.content').html(); // get content
    overview.html(thisContent);                        // set overview content
  });

  list.mouseleave(function() {
    startInterval();                                  // restart the interval on mouseleave
  });

  function startInterval() {
    // Change active tab every x seconds
    time = 5; // interval in seconds
    autoInterval = setInterval(function() {
      currentActive = (currentActive + 1) % list.length;
      list.removeClass('active');
      var currentTab = list.eq(currentActive);
      currentTab.addClass('active');
      overview.html(currentTab.find('.content').html()); // set overview content
    }, time * 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.tabs.active {
  background: none yellow;
}

.list {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.overview {
  flex-basis: 60%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="list">

    <li class="tabs active">
      <div class="header"><span>Header</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs">
      <div class="header"><span>Header 2</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="tabs">
      <div class="header"><span>Header 3</span></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>

  </div>
  <div class="overview"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, works exactly as envisioned + thank you for the comments too

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you add the `mouseenter` event, you need to stop the interval, you have the method `clearInterval` to do so.